# Extending the MS RDP client

Tags: rdp

I need to implement a custom compression algorithm for the Windows Remote Desktop.

Essentially I will have a Dynamic Virtual Channel addin through which I will send custom data. The example is quite straightforward, this part is doable.

My question is how do I customize the rendering part on the client?

Can I just create a child window on the main RDP client window and render stuff in it?

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding your question, but I don't think there are extension points to control rendering on the client side or server side. Virtual channels can be used to send additional data on top of the rendering data, but I don't think you can use them to control the rendering data itself.

Comment: I've been working on media redirection for SPICE, and it works great, now we need to extend it to RDP, so I was wondering how.

For the SPICE code, its reasonably simple, since everything is open source. Here I can't find a way to control rendering.

I wonder if the IWRdsGraphicsChannel interface is what I need.

There don't seem to be many code examples. Guess I'll have to work it out by trial and error